# Easy way to regenerate C# code for attributes found via reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection, code-generation

I'm making a program which uses reflection to examine enum types in an assembly and, in some cases, rewrite the C# source files defining those enums.

The source files in question are of a narrowly prescribed format which basically just defines the enum, possibly inside a partial class, so it was not too difficult to create a simple generator.

Unfortunately the situation is a bit more complicated when there are custom attributes on the enum, which in this application there typically will be.

I can use reflection to get a list of Attribute or CustomAttributeData objects.  Right now I am using an ad-hoc approach which assumes things about the particular attributes found and generates C# code for them on that basis, but I would prefer a more general approach.

Given an attribute, I can determine the type and trivially output code such as this if it is safe to assume that the attribute has no arguments:

```
[SomeNamespace.SomeAttribute]
```

Unfortunately, it is not safe to assume that no arguments are present, and if any are, it is not as simple to generate the required code.

Is there some existing mechanism in .NET or elsewhere that can generate the C# code for an attribute in the general case, given an attribute invocation we want to duplicate?  I checked the Attribute and CustomAttributeData classes but nothing in them seems to handle this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Type.GetCustomAttributesData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributesdata.aspx). Instead of providing you with a constructed `Attribute` instance, this will give you a [`CustomAttributesData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.customattributedata.aspx) object with individual access to the constructor, constructor arguments, and named arguments you'll need to reproduce the attribute as source code.

Comment: +1 Good point.  Forgot to mention I did know about CustomAttributeData as well.  It does provide the needed information, however it still requires a fair bit of work to actually generate the constructor invocation code in the general case.  It's not _that_ hard but still it feels like reinventing the wheel... (thus the question.)